# Error while Loading varbinary data into oracle raw column

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, binary, varbinary, raw

Create table temp(col raw(40));

Insert into temp values(0x02900000AB45GH38);

Error: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert Hex data into the oracle table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080589/how-to-insert-hex-data-into-the-oracle-table)

Answer (score 0):

First, your data is not correct hex - "GH" should not be there.

Once you get your data right,

Just pass hex as varchar -

```
Insert into temp values('0290')
```

It is same as -

```
Insert into temp values(hextoraw('0290'))
```